# How to loop through all the pages while scraping hundreds of pages on LinkedIn?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch the data of a specific role on LinkedIn. But, I don't know how to iterate through all the search results for extracting information. The number of search results are around 4191 (around 180-200 pages). Below is the code:

count = 1
while count <4192:

```
id_text = raw.find('code', {'id':'decoratedJobPostingsModule'})
data = []

for d in id_text:
    data.append(json.loads(d))

for num in range(0, len(data[0]['elements'])):

    job_site_link = data[0]['elements'][num]['companyTextUrl']
    company_name = data[0]['elements'][num]['decoratedJobPosting']['companyName']
    job_title = data[0]['elements'][num]['decoratedJobPosting']['jobPosting']['title']
    city = data[0]['elements'][num]['decoratedJobPosting']['formattedLocation']+" ("+data[0]['elements'][num]['decoratedJobPosting']['cityState']+")"

    result= result.append({'Job site Link':job_site_link, 'Company name':company_name, 'Job title':job_title, 'Company City':city,}, ignore_index=True)


count=count+1
```

Comment: LinkedIn has a REST API... could you get this information that way? This would be a much cleaner solution. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: Can you please give me a quick walkthrough on how to use the LinkedIn rest API?